# kickstart installation command paramters

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, vmware-esx

Does anyone know of any listing of the different parameters that can be used in the command when installing a unix/linux host via kickstart?  Specifically I'm look for ones in regards to ESX/Red Hat.  These are the ones I know of so far:

```
ks=          'Points to the .cfg install configuration file ftp/http/usb
ksdevice=    'indicates which ethernet adapter to use
ip=          'indicates what ip to use for install
netmask=     'indicates what netmask to use for install
gateway=     'indicates what gateway to use for install
nameserver=  'indicates what nameserver is in your enviornment
method=      'type of install i.e. cdrom (I don't know what other methods there are)
```

Is there one for hostname?, I thought there was, but after preforming the install, the name I gave fro the command "hostname=svr01.local" was not the resulted hostname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-startinginstall.html) is a list of kickstart options from the RHEL/CentOS 5.2 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a sample ESX 3.5 Kickstart script.  It seems in later versions of ESX, they are designating the hostname on the network config line.

[ESX Kickstart Scripts](http://blog.core-it.com.au/?p=39)

Comment: ironically that's actually the .cfg that I'm using as a reference...however my problem is that I want to use the same .cfg file for 32 hosts, all of which will be static not DHCP.  My current thought is too make them dhcp initially, and then switch to static based on the IP issued to them from DHCP. But I'm looking to see if there is an easier method.